# Alternating rows bootstrap using nth-of-type

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make the bootstrap columns change order, so every other row they alternate. This is easy to do if it's a flat site but I'm using the WP loop so need to target every other column set with CSS.

My current code is below, but this seems to be targeting every .odd element not just every other element. I've tried child and type.

**HTML**

```
<div class="alternate">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="services-content row">
                    <div class="col-8 odd"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
                    <div class="col-4 even"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>" /></div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="services-content row">
                    <div class="col-8 odd"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
                    <div class="col-4 even"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>" /></div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.alternate .odd:nth-of-type(odd){
    order: 1;
}
```

Of course the code above shows only one 'odd' but the jumbotron section is repeated many times (I just removed the PHP).

Can anyone see what's wrong? I'm thinking it's a nesting issue maybe?

Comment: what do you want? @MonkeyFace

Comment: If there is only two elements inside the `row`, it works. Otherwise, it won't

Comment: so you want to target only odd element right?

Comment: To explain it better I've added some more HTML - this is how it looks on the front end. So every other odd element within the 'alternate' container needs to change order.

Comment: maybe simply this `.alternate :nth-of-type(odd){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nth-child(odd)` on `jumbotron` and select `col-8` to alternate the columns.

```css
.jumbotron:nth-child(odd) .col-8 {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="alternate">
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perferendis molestias numquam, culpa, ullam sed quia facilis debitis fuga dolore obcaecati tenetur asperiores? Aspernatur, fugit veritatis? Fugit ex aspernatur velit dolorem?
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/XA-UHZ_%286908943182%29.jpg" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 ">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perferendis molestias numquam, culpa, ullam sed quia facilis debitis fuga dolore obcaecati tenetur asperiores? Aspernatur, fugit veritatis? Fugit ex aspernatur velit dolorem?
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/XA-UHZ_%286908943182%29.jpg" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perferendis molestias numquam, culpa, ullam sed quia facilis debitis fuga dolore obcaecati tenetur asperiores? Aspernatur, fugit veritatis? Fugit ex aspernatur velit dolorem?
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/XA-UHZ_%286908943182%29.jpg" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 ">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perferendis molestias numquam, culpa, ullam sed quia facilis debitis fuga dolore obcaecati tenetur asperiores? Aspernatur, fugit veritatis? Fugit ex aspernatur velit dolorem?
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/XA-UHZ_%286908943182%29.jpg" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check the code snippet in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.alternate .jumbotron:nth-child(odd) .odd {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="alternate">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="services-content row">
                    <div class="col-8 odd">odd</div>
                    <div class="col-4 even">test</div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="services-content row">
                    <div class="col-8 odd">odd</div>
                    <div class="col-4 even">test</div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="services-content row">
                    <div class="col-8 odd">odd</div>
                    <div class="col-4 even">test</div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```